# How do I create and use keyboard shortcuts in a Gtk app that I am developing?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk, shortcut-keys

I am creating an application for the Ubuntu App Showdown in Python + Gtk with quickly. I am calling it Discvur. I would have liked to include some keyboard shortcuts.

Searching the web, I found [this page about AccelGroup](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/gtk-Keyboard-Accelerators.html) and [this page about gtk_widget_add_accelerator](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-add-accelerator) but I don't understand how to start with it. Could you tell me how I would define an appropriate signal and then use it in my application?

Comment: The first link is broken...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code that finally worked. As it depends highly on my development environment Quickly + Glade + Python + Gtk, I make it an independent answer. [Bryce's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153501/how-do-i-create-and-use-keyboard-shortcuts-in-a-gtk-app-that-i-am-developing/153502#153502) helped a lot, and so did my exchanges with [aking1012](https://askubuntu.com/users/5768/aking1012).

The actual code, in a text editor:

```
# Accelerators
self.my_accelerators = Gtk.AccelGroup()
self.window = self.builder.get_object("discvur_window")
self.window.add_accel_group(self.my_accelerators)
self.entry = self.builder.get_object("entry1")
self.add_accelerator(self.entry, "<Control>b", signal="backspace")

…

def add_accelerator(self, widget, accelerator, signal="activate"):
    """Adds a keyboard shortcut"""
    if accelerator is not None:
        #if DEBUG:
            #print accelerator, widget.get_tooltip_text()
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
        widget.add_accelerator(signal, self.my_accelerators, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
        print "The accelerator is well added with the signal " + signal

def on_erasing(self, widget):
    print "It works."
```

In Glade, I created a GtkEntry called "entry1" in my window called "discvur_window". In 
the 'Signals' tab, I gave the signal "backspace" a handler called "on_erasing".

Now, hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> makes the terminal print "It works.".

Comment: Can this be used to disable Ctrl+F4 shortcut to close the window?

Comment: You mean Alt+F4 ? I don't know, I haven't tried.

Comment: I meant both Ctrl+F4 and Alt+F4

Answer (score 8):

Here's some bits of code from one of my Python + Gtk apps, further extended according to the comments to this answer:

```
self.my_accelerators = Gtk.AccelGroup()
self.entry = Gtk.builder.get_object("entry1")
self.add_accelerator(self.entry, "<Control>b", signal="backspace")
...

def add_accelerator(self, widget, accelerator, signal="activate"):
    """Adds a keyboard shortcut"""
    if accelerator is not None:
        #if DEBUG:
            #print accelerator, widget.get_tooltip_text()
        key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
        widget.add_accelerator(signal, self.my_accelerators, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)
```

Comment: Thank you but I got this error: `self.add_accelerator(self.quick_add_entry, "<Control>l", signal="grab-focus")   
AttributeError: 'DiscvurWindow' object has no attribute 'quick_add_entry'`. When I try a web search of "quick_add_entry", I cannot find it anywhere. Are you sure it is the right function? Where can I find more information/a tutorial for this? Additionally, does "<Control>l" mean Ctrl + l or is it a mistype?

Comment: It's not a function, that's just the name of whatever widget you're connecting the accelerator to.  I've revised it to be clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First, I took the liberty to change the "gtk" into "Gtk". Second, when I run your code I get "NameError: global name 'DEBUG' is not defined", so I suppose this is a variable from your own script. So I commented it in my own script. Third, after having commented it, I get the error "AttributeError: 'DiscvurWindow' object has no attribute 'accelerators'". I am sorry if this is supposed to be evident but the documentation is still obscure to me; in particular the documentation says add_accelerator needs 6 arguments?

Comment: Right, you need to create accelerators yourself; I've updated the example to show how.

Comment: After a little research and failed tries, I could get a working script. Could you please verify it? If you think it is correct, I will (or you can) modify your answer: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1053516/. I would appreciate your review a lot, Bryce. "A little research" was a euphemism, but I suppose it is better to learn a man how to fish than giving him fish. So thank you again.

Comment: It looks good, although instead of passing in '1' as the arg to Gtk.AccelFlags, use one of the defined constants, shown at http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-constants.html#gtk-accel-flags-constants

Comment: I faced a big problem indeed with Gtk.ACCEL_VISIBLE… Should I try Gtk.Accelflags(ACCEL_VISIBLE)"? I will try as soon as I get on my development computer.

Comment: However I type ACCEL_VISIBLE, I always get "NameError: global name 'ACCEL_VISIBLE' is not defined", so I don't know how to include it. If you know a tutorial about my question, it would be very welcome.

Comment: The Gtk docs said they moved most constants out of the global namespace.  dir(Gtk) from a python shell, copy paste the output in to something where you can search text, oh look the class...dir(Gtk.AccelFlags) and there's VISIBLE.  Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE should work fine.  The output of `print Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE` tells you it's the right type.

Comment: Hitting Crtl+b in the running app still does nothing. I had expected it to erase some letters of my entry field? What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is "entry1"?

Answer (score 3):

I've repackaged the given answers in this thread into a standalone example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import signal

from gi.repository import Gtk

def bind_accelerator(accelerators, widget, accelerator, signal='clicked'):
    key, mod = Gtk.accelerator_parse(accelerator)
    widget.add_accelerator(signal, accelerators, key, mod, Gtk.AccelFlags.VISIBLE)

def on_recompute_base_encryption_key_hash(widget):
    print 'Thinking... (This could take forever)'

def main():

    if 'gtk':
        window = Gtk.Window()
        window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        if 'accelerator-demo':
            # Accelerators
            accelerators = Gtk.AccelGroup()
            window.add_accel_group(accelerators)

            # Widget
            target_widget = Gtk.Button('Recompute Base Encryption Key Hash')
            target_widget.connect('clicked', on_recompute_base_encryption_key_hash)
            window.add(target_widget)

            # Bind
            bind_accelerator(accelerators, target_widget, '<Control>b')

        window.show_all()
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
        Gtk.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> Also available as a gist: https://gist.github.com/thorsummoner/230bed5bbd3380bd5949

**Note:** The default signal is `clicked`, not `activate` because [Applications should never connect to the `::activate` signal, but use the Gtk.Button `::clicked` signal.](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#Gtk.Button.signals.activate)

Comment: So I noticed; when using `clicked` the accelerator can be mashed very quickly, but the button doesn't visually depress. When using `activate`, the button will depress, but the accelerator can only be pressed once the visual depress is finished.